# download and rename links in shell/unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, curl

I have many links to download and save them in a specific structure as it is given in the link address. Example I have the following links:

```
https://example.com/alldata/abc/jkfa.txt?param1=12131&param2=87438er
https://example.com/alldata/abc/fjessd.jpg?param1=sdfsdfs&param2=adsad
.
.
.
https://example.com/alldata/viaeeui/jkacnsa.png?param1=kfjweiuw&param2=evuwids
```

The files and sub-directories have totally random patterns, and I am going to download them in following path:

```
/alldata/abc/jkfa.txt
/alldata/abc/fjessd.jpg
/alldata/viaeeui/jkacnsa.png
```

I had successful experience with `curl` when I enter the download link and rename manually such as here:

```
 curl -o  "/alldata/abc/jkfa.txt" --create-dirs "https://example.com/alldata/abc/jkfa.txt?param1=12131&param2=87438er"
```

however, I could not automate this process.

Comment: `htttps` is that the real url or you just have too many t's in the sample urls?

Comment: O that is a typo I will fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a `while` + `read` loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r urls; do
  [[ -z "$urls" ]] && continue
  files="${urls%\?*}"
  echo curl -o "'/${files#*http*.*/}'" --create-dirs "'$urls'"
done < file.txt
```

---

I'm not sure if the embedded single quotes are necessary.

The `file.txt` can be replaced with the command that generates the links, something like. ([Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html))

```
< <(command_that_generates_the_links)
```

Instead of

```
< file.txt
```

---

Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output but the single quotes can cause some errors or not, just remove them if need be.

Comment: thanks for your answer. My command to generate the links are in pipelines such as ```cat links.txt | grep xxxxxx | ... ``` how should I replace them with `file.txt`

Comment: `< <(grep xxxxxx links.txt | .... )` No need to bother the `cat`

Comment: I get this error: ```./download.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('```

Comment: Use `bash` not `sh`

Comment: I still get the same error. I run it with `$bash download.sh` and get 
```download.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('```

Comment: paste your actual code. There are two `<` in that syntax and a space in between them. Separate the `<` with a space...

Comment: ```#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r urls; do
  [[ -z "$urls" ]] && continue
  files="${urls%\?*}"
  echo curl -o "'/${files#*http*.*/}'" --create-dirs "'$urls'"
done < ( ./mc share list download | grep Share: | grep -o https:\/\/.*  )```

Comment: `< ( ./mc share list download...` missing a `<` I have already a sample code just replace what is inside the `(  )`

Comment: Thank you, it is generating the commands I want, however it is not saving the files. This can be because of the generated path, how can I add a path prefix to the saving path `/home/user/...`?

Comment: Just add it after the `curl -o` at the variable `files`

Comment: Thanks very much. just a note. I had to `bash download.sh > dl.sh ` and then run ./dl.sh to download because your solution generates the commands but not performing them.

Comment: Remove the `echo` so curl can actually  download and execute some commands, it is written at my post/answer.